# Azure SQL Server security

Tags: sql-server, security, azure

When you're creating an `SQL server` on `Azure`, there is the option to

> "ALLOW WINDOWS AZURE SERVICES TO ACCESS THE SERVER."

Does this mean that some other application (other than my own applications) hosted on Azure, like a website, can access my sql server?

There is username password, of course, but I'm afraid they can be brute forced.

Is this a legitimate concern?

Comment: I can't believe that Azure SQL Server doesn't have VPC like isolation after reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-control-access This is so inconvenient and insecure.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, "Allow access to Azure services" is a shortcut that allows any Azure-hosted service through the firewall (though the other service still needs to know the server name and a SQL Authentication username/password, as you mention). This shortcut is for convenience, since your app's IP address can change if the VMs in your cloud service fail over or shut down.

To avoid using this shortcut, you could create a [reserved virtual IP address](https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-reserved-public-ip/) (VIP) for your cloud service. This allows your app to have a persistent public IP address, which you can specifically and selectively allow through the server firewall for your SQL Database.

Comment: What is the difference between a Reserved Virtual IP and a Public IP that is set to static?  Can the static one be moved around with failures like you said, whereas the Reserved VIP doesn't?